# Need advice applying for UK Visitor Visa with mother from Pakistan

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, family

Hope you all are doing well.

I have two questions:

- I want to travel with my mother to visit my aunt in UK. But people say that my chances will improve if I apply alone first. What do you guys think? My mother already has a visa to Canada and has been to the UK before.
- What are my chances overall to get a visa?

Here is my profile:

- I was rejected 3 times in 2017 for a visitor visa to UK to visit my aunt because I was a student with no assets and ties to home country.
- Now I have a good salary and bank balance with properly maintained bank statements.
- I am unmarried and live with my family (Mother and siblings).
- I have traveled to Turkey and UAE twice in the past 5 years.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The circumstances has improved a lot in 5 years. So, you should be ok.

The reason behind that random advice that proof that you will return to Pakistan after your visit. You have to prove the ties to family and society. For that, if your mother is not coming with you, there is a more chance that you are coming back to be with her. It may not work out that way always.

But, as you mentioned, you have steady income and a good job in your country. You have been to other countries and returned promptly, showing that you can be trusted to comply with visa policy and return. So, no issues in that side. Just be straight forward. Show all the evidence you have. There are great answers in this site for that. All the best for your visa.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

But I just have one confusion. If I apply with my mother and they grant her visa, they are signaling that they trust my mother to come back to Pakistan. In this case they cannot say that I do not have family ties since they are expecting my mother to come back to Pakistan. 

What do you think? Since I really don't want to apply separately due to logistical and document gathering issues.

Comment: @taq12345 Do not apply separately if you are planning to go together. That's borderline deception and will hurt your application more.

Comment: @taq12345 You don't have to worry much as your situation did improve definitely.

Comment: If you have land or any immovable assets in your name, that will also help to establish your ties to pakistan.

Comment: Yeah thanks I'll apply together then. I have a car in my name and my mother has property in her name. I hope that would be enough. Btw is it advisable to write one invitation letter for both or separate would work as well? @Anish

Comment: @taq12345 Since you are travelling together, one invitation letter for both will be fine.